# PHP in TOMCAT 6 - Exception

Tags: php, tomcat

I have been trying to integrate `PHP` in `APACHE TOMCAT 6` by following `second answer` for the [QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779246/run-a-php-app-using-tomcat) RUN PHP APP IN TOMCAT 6. I am facing troubles with the configuration.

1. First I got Exception `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no php5srvlt in java.library.path`. which I resolved by placing `php5srvlt.jar`, generated in `step 12`, in `tomcat\lib`.
2. After that I am facing

   ```
   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: net.php.servlet.send(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Z)V
   net.php.servlet.send(Native Method)
   net.php.servlet.service(servlet.java:190)
   net.php.servlet.service(servlet.java:214)
   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
   ```

   Exception.

I tried to find solutions for this but could only get close to this [QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199148/configuring-php-on-tomcat-gives-exception-unsatisfiedlinkerror). But, I do not want to do the whole thing once again, because I have tried several times. I tried with TOMCAT 8.0.15, but failed. Now, just to go in sink with the instructions I have installed TOMCAT 6 and trying to integrate PHP.

I am placing log file for the request made for tomcat/webapps/PHP/test.php.

**LOCALHOST.YYYY-MM-DD.log**

```
Dec 29, 2014 12:15:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet php threw exception
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: net.php.servlet.send(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Z)V
at net.php.servlet.send(Native Method)
at net.php.servlet.service(servlet.java:190)
at net.php.servlet.service(servlet.java:214)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:879)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1778)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

**TEST.PHP**

```
<?php 
echo "HELLO WORLD";
?>
```

**EDIT**

I mistook that I was getting `problem 1` because i did not have `php5srvlt.jar` in `tomcat/lib`. But, in fact, `problem 1` appears when i request the page for the first time after starting the server. and later on I see `problem 2`.

I've learned from [here](http://tech.gaeatimes.com/index.php/archive/running-php-5x-on-windows-using-tomcat-4x-or-5x/#comment-528998) that php and pecl version must be same, but still I get the same error even after working with same version numbers `5.2.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message [indicates that you're missing .dll-files](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-how-to-handle-unsatisfied-link-error/) necessary for such a .. fragile contraption.

> The UnsatisfiedLinkError is thrown when an application attempts to load a native library like .so in Linux, .dll on Windows or .dylib in Mac and that library does not exist.

But please - reconsider what you're actually doing. There is (almost) no good reason for running a PHP context inside Tomcat.

Comment: I am actually trying to run php files on my apache tomcat server to respond to ajax calls. Instead of getting an echo message back to responseText, I am getting entire file. Therefore, I thought I should have a php parser so that only the echo message will get back to me. If this is not a good way, How do I do it?

Comment: Run PHP in a suitable context, either using Apache and FCGI/mod_php, or nginx + php-fpm or other options. PHP is not written, nor tested, for running inside Tomcat. Use Tomcat as an application server for Java based applications, which is what it was made for.