# ajax responseText contains php source code

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, tomcat, responsetext

I am trying to make a `ajax` call and validate a `input html field`. But, instead of getting simple `echo message`. I am getting complete source code in `responseText`.

**JavaScript**

```
function checkUsername() {
document.getElementById("username").className = "thinking";
usernameRequest = createRequest();
if (usernameRequest == null)
    alert("Unable to create request");
else {
    var theName = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var username = escape(theName);
    var url= "checkName.php?username=" + username;
    usernameRequest.onreadystatechange = showUsernameStatus;
    usernameRequest.open("GET", url, true);
    usernameRequest.send(null);
    }
}

function showUsernameStatus() {
    alert(usernameRequest.responseText);

    if (usernameRequest.readyState == 4) 
    {
       if (usernameRequest.status == 200) {
       if (usernameRequest.responseText == "okay") {
           document.getElementById("username").className = "approved";
           document.getElementById("register").disabled = false;
       } 
       else {
           document.getElementById("username").className = "denied";
           document.getElementById("username").focus();
           document.getElementById("username").select();
           document.getElementById("register").disabled = true;
       }
       }
   }
 }
```

**checkName.php**

```
<?php
$takenUsernames = array('bill', 'ted');
sleep(2);
if (!in_array($_REQUEST['username'],$takenUsernames )) {
    echo 'okay';
} else {
echo 'denied';
?>
```

Previously, I tried to integrate PHP into tomcat, but I was advice it was not a good practice. [TRIAL TO INTEGRATE PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27684584/php-in-tomcat-6-exception)

What I can make out of this situation is that Tomcat is not parsing PHP file and instead it is returning the source code. I believe there should be a means for me to let tomcat parse php files and send the right response.

I have also tried with simple php code, with one statment `<?php echo 'HELLO'; ?>` and I still get the source code. 
Thanks in advance.

*NOTE : I do not know php, I am working an example from HEAD FIRST AJAX*

Comment: add die after the echo then it will output your text only.

Comment: @MikeClark It still does not work. `die("Message");` before `?>`.

Comment: What is the name of your php file?

Comment: `checkName.php`, but since I am getting source code, I don't think tomcat has a problem finding the file in the directory.

Comment: Yeah usually people forget to name it with the `.php` extension (sounds dumb but happens a lot), so if you have a valid php file, then that is not the problem.

Comment: probably you don't have php installed so the server returns the file as text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to install PHP for Tomcat & set its path to compile it.see the below link for php configuration settings.

http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/doc/tomcat6.php
http://www.studytrails.com/blog/php-on-a-java-app-server-apache-tomcat-using-quercus/

Comment: It does not work, I am getting UnsatisfiedLinkError and few others.

Comment: Please check that php is installed on on the same both or correct environment path is set for running php.

Comment: Could you give me a better link, because I have tried multiple times with that link and did not succeed.

Comment: http://www.studytrails.com/blog/php-on-a-java-app-server-apache-tomcat-using-quercus/